# Oracle execution plan WHERE 1=1

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I'm using an Oracle database, but I don't have access to admin tools like running an execution plan.

Using SQL Server, it seems that the SQL/database/query (?) engine will completely ignore an expression in the `WHERE` clause like...

```
1=1
```

...where `1` can be replaced with any literal value as long as the values match.

How does Oracle handle this?  Does Oracle also ignore the expression?

What I'm getting at is, which is faster?

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TBL
```

or

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TBL
WHERE C IN (<every distinct value in C>)
```

Comment: so what does the Oracle execution plan show you?

Comment: "...I don't have access to admin tools like running an execution plan."

Comment: Go somewhere, where you have access? One of the many fiddle sites or Oracle Live? Install Oracle on your own machine?

Comment: I feel like the optimizer will just ignore 1=1, as that's always true. `where c in (<values of c>)' the engine will need to work out all the values of c before using that list in the where clause. I would put money on the query without the where clause being faster theoretically faster. I don't see it being practically faster, in that you probably won't notice a difference

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 1` is trivially eliminated, and even where not, trivially evaluated; `WHERE C IN (<anything>)` cannot be eliminated, since the contents of `TBL` matter -- this is true even if `<anything>` happens to be a list of all distinct values at some given moment. This is basically true in any database engine you'd care to name, unless it had some special feature for (say) restricting the type of `C` to an enumeration of fixed values.

Comment: If you have a SQL client where you can run SQL statements, you can get the execution plan

Comment: As no-one would ever write a query like this, why do you care? Is there some real-world use case you are trying to understand and this is just a simplified version of an an actual query?

Comment: The reporting system I'm working with is designed to do either of these.  There is an "All" value that works like `WHERE 1=1` and there is a "Select All" button that is intended to cause every possible value to be used with the `IN` operator.  So yes, people [using systems] do write queries like both of these every day.  I'm trying to decide the best options to present to the users to offer better report performance for them.  (And yes, my examples are simplified to the extreme.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Report generators often add unnecessary code, and it's helpful to know which is harmless and which is potentially harmful. An extra `1=1` predicate is almost certainly harmless. But the `C IN (<every distinct value in C>)` may potentially lead to bugs and performance issues and should be avoided.

### 1=1 - Allow it

While I can't prove that the predicate never causes a problem, based on my experience and some simple tests, I can confidently say that `1=1` will never give you a problem. Myself and others have encountered this extra predicate many times and never seen an issue. And the below simple test case shows that the predicate does not even appear in the explain plan. The optimizer recognizes it as junk and removes it at compile time.

```
explain plan for select * from dual where 1=1;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 272002086
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### C IN (every distinct value in C) - Avoid it

One minor reason to avoid extra lists of values is that users may incorrectly modify them for NULL comparisons. A condition like `C IN (1,2,3)` is simple, but the comparisons get more complicated if there are NULLs. You might want to avoid this unnecessary code before someone incorrectly modifies it to `C IN (1,2,3,NULL)`. Or possibly the system will forget to update the values. This is a "real" line of code, and removing it can reduce the number of potential errors.

There are also some potential performance implications of unnecessarily comparing values. The actual comparisons themselves are likely irrelevant - the CPU can trivially check `C IN (1,2,3)`. The real problem is that unnecessary comparisons give Oracle another potential way to create an execution plan, one that may mislead the optimizer into using a slow access paths.

For example, let's say we start off with a small table, with just one row and one value for C:

```
create table tbl(a number, b number, c number);
insert into tbl select 1, 2, 3 from dual;
create index tbl_c on tbl(c);
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TBL');
end;
/
```

There's only one row so it barely matters how Oracle retrieves the data. On my system, it usese an index range scan

```
explain plan for select * from tbl where c = 3;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1444222704
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |       |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TBL   |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TBL_C |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("C"=3)
```

Here comes the problem. Somebody inserted a million rows, all with the same simple value, but forgot to gather statistics on the table afterwards. Reading a million rows one-at-a-time from an index is much less efficient than simply scanning the entire table. But since that `WHERE C = 3` predicate is there, Oracle *thinks* that using the index is still fast:

```
insert into tbl select 1,2,3 from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
commit;

explain plan for select * from tbl where c = 3;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--(Same plan as above)
```

Whereas, if that predicate is removed, there's no chance to pick a bad index range scan. Instead, we see a full table scan in the below explain plan:

```
explain plan for select * from tbl;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 2144214008
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TBL  |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```